# Django how to deal with foreign keys in child tables

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I am new in DJango. I have a database with three tables:

```
> -CRP
>  - SubComponents of a CRP
>     - Objectives of a SubComponent of a CRP.
```

I have the following models:

```
class period(models.Model):
    period_code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,verbose_name='Period code')
    period_desc = models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='Period description')
    period_current = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Current period')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.period_desc
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'period'

class crp(models.Model):
    crp_code = models.CharField(max_length=3,primary_key=True,verbose_name='CRP code')
    crp_desc = models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='CRP description')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.crp_desc
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'crp'

class subcomponent(models.Model):
    crp_code = models.ForeignKey(crp,db_column='crp_code',related_name='subcomponent_crp_code',to_field='crp_code',primary_key=True,verbose_name='CRP code')
    subc_code = models.CharField(max_length=3,primary_key=True,verbose_name='SubComponent Code')
    subc_desc = models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='SubComponent Description')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subc_desc
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'subcomponent'

class objective(models.Model):
    crp_code = models.ForeignKey(subcomponent,db_column='crp_code',related_name='objective_crp_code',to_field='crp_code',primary_key=True,verbose_name='CRP code')
    subc_code = models.ForeignKey(subcomponent,db_column='subc_code',related_name='objective_subc_code',to_field='subc_code',primary_key=True,verbose_name='SubComponent Code')
    obj_year = models.ForeignKey(period,db_column='obj_year',related_name='objective_obj_year',to_field='period_code',primary_key=True,verbose_name='Objective year')
    obj_code = models.CharField(max_length=7,primary_key=True,verbose_name='Objective code')
    obj_desc = models.CharField(max_length=45,verbose_name='Objective description')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.obj_desc
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'objective'
```

All works fine for the "subcomponent" model (reference to CRP); in the administration of "subcomponent" the user can pull down a CRP and add a subcomponent to it.

However, the model "objective" reference the model "subcomponent". In the administration of "objective" I would like the user to pull down and select a CRP, then filter the subcomponents of that CRP also in a pull down list. How can I do this?

Many thanks,
Carlos.

Comment: You'd need to use ajax or a multi step form. Data is not exchanged with the server from HTML actions such as selecting an item in a drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that smart-select can solve the problem. However it is concatenating "_id" to my keys and thus producing an error... Sadly its support is very poor.

Comment: It worked flawlessly for me few weeks ago. Maybe it's it's because of `db_column` in your models?